# Adding objects to a dynamic list in java

Tags: java, list

I have a list with a syntax similar to this:

```
List<? extends MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have an object that implements `MyInterface`, but using the above code, I am unable to add that object to the list:

```
Object object = getMyObject(); // I can only receive it here as Object
list.add((MyImplementation)object);
```

The following doesn't work either:

```
list.add((MyInterface)object);
```

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you should read [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: tl;dr: the static type of `object` is `Object`. Thus, the compiler (rightfully) rejects `list.add(object)`. Please keep in mind that [types are erased after compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), thus Java has no chance to "see" that `object` is, in fact, `implements MyImplementation`. As @csmckelvey mentioned, you should apply PECS (Producer `extends` - Consumer `super`), i.e. use `super` instead of `extends` since your `list` consumes some `MyImplemntation`.